# php Insert line break after certain character is found

Tags: php

I'm trying to clean a CSS script, which consists of a single line, like this:

```
footer .column .f-links li a{color:#1297de;font-size:14px}footer .column .address{font-size:14px;color:#3d3d3d}footer .column .infos{margin-top:10px;color:#3d3d3d}footer .column .infos .phone{background:url("../images/icon-phone.png") no-repeat 0 2px;padding:0 0 0 25px;margin-bottom:10px}@media (min-width:1023px) and (max-width:1024px){footer .column .infos .phone{font-size:10px;line-height:24px;padding-top:7px}footer .column .infos .email{font-size:10px;padding-top:7px}}
```

and i would like to insert a line break before and after the characters "{" and "}" respectively.

I appreciate your comments.

Comment: `$str=str_replace(array('{','}'),array("\n{\n","\n}\n"),$str);`

Comment: There also exist tools/web applications to *Unminify* stuff, which is essentially what a single line `.css` file is (generally speaking anyway).

Comment: He didn't ask for indent! ;)

Comment: This did it, haha, Thank you very much, i'm new to all this, and i'm learning some php, but who knew there was a way to make this rubbish legible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function:

```
str_replace(['{', '}'], ["\r\n}", "}\r\n"], $string);
```